# Angular Material 15 (mdc) - How to change the width of matToolTip?

Tags: angular-material

How to change the width of matToolTip (Angular Material 15 - the new MDC classes). I would like to show the entire tooltip in one line.

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
 <div matTooltip="This is a super loooooooooong tooltip This is a super loooooooooong tooltip">
    <button disabled="true">Next</button>
 </div>
```

```scss
::ng-deep .mdc-tooltip__surface {
  width: 500px !important;
}
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Thanks in advance!